# How to detect when SKEmitterNode has emitted all the particles in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skemitternode

It's possible to limit the number of particles emitted in a `SKEmitterNode` by setting `numParticlesToEmit` to, for example, 100. How do I detect when the `SKEmitterNode` has emitted all the particles?

Comment: Could not find anything after a bit of digging :/

Comment: Dividing `numParticlesToEmit` by `particleBirthRate` gives the total time it takes to emit the particles.